# Is there a way to select all elements in a page which contains a class which includes text 'button'?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose we have a Html element, I want to select all such elements in a page whose class contains a text 'button'. It need not be exactly 'button'. In this case the class is 'button-success', so that too needs to be selected. The aim is to go to random url and get all the button tags

```
<a class="nav-link button-success create-new-button" id="createbuttonDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#">+ Create Project</a>
```

Till now I have figured this much ways to select buttons

```
const btnSelectedUsingClassBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
const btnSelectedUsingClassButton = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
const btnSelectedUsingTagName = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
const btnSelectedUsingType = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
const btnSelectedUsingRole = document.querySelectorAll('[role="button"]');
```

Is there any more ways to get the buttons ? And is there way we can select button from CMS websites such as wordpress , wix , squarespace etc. They need not have the class with name buttons in it. is there a word-around to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can select them all in a single query:

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll("button, [class*=button], [type=button], [role=presentation]");
console.log(items);
```

```html
<div class="button">Button</div>
<div class="button-success">Button Success</div>
<div class="button-failure">Button Failure</div>
<button>Button</button>
<input type=button value="Input Button" />
<div role="presentation">Presentation Button</div>
```

Comment: Oh Thanks, Actually I wanted to compare the each aray to find the maxLength array and further work on that array

Comment: Is this the method - [class*=button] , to select elements with class containing button ?

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I might have misunderstood your question.`[class*=button]` will select all elements whose class list contains, `button` string.

Comment: No, my mistake. I didn't give the full purpose of the problem, as I thought it would be irrelevant here